# How do I add a filter to my custom post type archive page?

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, advanced-custom-fields

I used the guide [HERE](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-wp-archive-custom-field-filter/) from acf themselves, but for some reason whenever I attempt to query anything at all in the url I get the "There has been a critical error on this website" error.

```php
$GLOBALS['my_query_filters'] = array( 
    'field_1'   => 'bedrooms', 
);
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');

function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    // bail early if is in admin
    if( is_admin() ) return;
    
    // get meta query
    $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');

    // loop over filters
    foreach( $GLOBALS['my_query_filters'] as $param => $key ) {
        // continue if not found in url
        if( !empty($_GET[ $param ]) ) {
            $value = explode(',', $_GET[ $param ]);
            
            // append meta query
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key'       => $key,
                'value'     => $value,
                'compare'   => 'IN',
            );
        }
    }
    
    // update meta query
    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

    return;
}
```

Here is the code I used, almost verbatim what is used in the tutorial and yet I have had no success. I've tried on two completely separate websites, one using a theme created by the Create Block Theme plugin and the site editor and the other using a custom theme fully coded out. In the latter one it uses a standard WP_Query loop to output all the posts from the particular post type.

Comment: if you are storing data and you want/need to filter posts by its value, then post meta/fields is not the best way to do that, and carries a heavy performance penalty. Instead use taxonomies, this is why tags and categories are not stored in post meta/fields, you'll see a massive performance boost, the queries are easier to write, and your filter dropdown can just be links to term archives in those taxonomies. You'll get pretty URLs for free, as well as support for templates and dedicated REST API endpoints for using AJAX

Comment: appreciate the reply! @TomJNowell but unfortunately this is a pretty specific use case. we imported a whole lot of books from a client who was not using a WP site and applied some custom fields to each of the books like ID/book authors. Ideally we'd just want to have the filters go through by book author for example